# How to pass multiple bootstrap actions in AWS EMR using Terraform?

Tags: emr, terraform

I am trying to create a terraform module for AWS EMR cluster. I need to run multiple bootstrap scripts in EMR, where I am having errors.
For example:

main.tf

```
  ...
  variable bootstrap_actions { type = "list"}
  ...    
  resource "aws_emr_cluster" "emr-cluster" {
  name          = "${var.emr_name}"

  release_label = "${var.release_label}"
  applications  = "${var.applications}"

  termination_protection = true

  ec2_attributes {
    subnet_id                         = "${data.aws_subnet.subnet.id}"
    emr_managed_master_security_group = "${data.aws_security_group.emr_managed_master_security_group.id}"
    emr_managed_slave_security_group  = "${data.aws_security_group.emr_managed_slave_security_group.id}"
    service_access_security_group     = "${data.aws_security_group.service_access_security_group.id}"
    additional_slave_security_groups  = "${var.additional_slave_security_groups_id}"
    instance_profile                  = "${var.instance_profile}"
    key_name                          = "${var.key_name}"
  }

  master_instance_type = "${var.master_instance_type}"
  core_instance_type   = "${var.core_instance_type}"
  core_instance_count  = "${var.core_instance_count}"

  tags {
      BUSINESS_UNIT = "${var.BUSINESS_UNIT}"
      BUSINESS_REGION = "${var.BUSINESS_REGION}"
      CLIENT = "${var.CLIENT}"
      ENVIRONMENT = "${var.env}"
      PLATFORM = "${var.PLATFORM}"
      Name = "${var.emr_name}"
  }


  bootstrap_action = "${var.bootstrap_actions}"

  configurations = "test-fixtures/emr_configurations.json"

  service_role = "${var.service_role}"
  autoscaling_role = "${var.autoscaling_role}"

}
```

I passed all the variables including bootstrap as :

```
bootstrap_actions = [ "path=s3://bucket/bootstrap/hive/metastore/JSON41.sh,name=SERDE","path=s3://bucket/bootstrap/hive/hive-nofile-nproc-increase.sh,name=ulimit" ]
```

When I am applying the plan, I am getting error:

```
* aws_emr_cluster.emr-cluster: bootstrap_action.0: expected object, got invalid
* aws_emr_cluster.emr-cluster: bootstrap_action.1: expected object, got invalid
```

Does anyone have any idea on it? How can I pass multiple bootstrap actions here.
Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It works :

```
bootstrap_action = [
        {
          name = "custombootrstrap_test1"
          path = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.bucketlogs.bucket}/bootstrap-actions/master/configure-test1.sh"
        },
        {
          name = "custombootrstrap_test2"
          path = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.bucketlogs.bucket}/bootstrap-actions/master/configure-test2.sh"
        },
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should probably look more like this, https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/22416

```
bootstrap_action {
path = "s3://${var.emrS3LogUri}/folder1/folder2/emr1.sh"
name = "emr1"
args = ["s3://${var.emrS3LogUri}/folder1/certs/", var.s3BucketRegion]
}

bootstrap_action {
path = "s3://${var.emrS3LogUri}/folder1/folder2/emr2.sh"
name = "emr2"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Doc: `bootstrap_action` - (Optional) list of bootstrap actions that will be run before Hadoop is started on the cluster nodes.

Your variable is list of strings, not list of objects. This variable is probably ok (not tested):

```
bootstrap_actions = [
  {
    path = "s3://bucket/bootstrap/hive/metastore/JSON41.sh"
    name = "SERDE"
  },
  {
    path = "s3://bucket/bootstrap/hive/hive-nofile-nproc-increase.sh"
    name = "ulimit"
  },
]
```